# Monitoring the Azure app services

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-web-app-service

I was wondering if someone can shed some lights on the application monitoring and alerting solution that's being used to specifically monitor the Azure app service. We have multiple API apps running on App service service and we would like to monitor certain metrics (ex: Availability, response time, number of request received, etc). I enabled the application insight on each of these apps and the result is quite promising, it fulfills all my requirement, but there's one small issue: I need to scroll through each app to see their performance. I can't aggregate them all in one space. I would like to create a centralized dashboard for all aforementioned metrics and have them displayed. I tried using OMS but it seems to be lacking a lot of functionality.

Any pointer would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote recently about it on our blog: http://predica.pl/blog/azure-monitoring-and-auditing/ - you will find link to MS documentation also there.

If you are using App Insights already you should be able to pick things from App Insights and put it on the Azure portal dashboard. Other than that probably getting data into Power Bi application insight is your best shot - https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-application-insights/

Comment: Thanks a ton, I will definitely go through your blog.

Comment: This may also be a useful link for anyone that finds this question: [Separating telemetry from Development, Test, and Production](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-separate-resources)